# Does Session Stickiness generally improve performance in Rails apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application running Rails 4.2.5 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with a MySQL RDS instance.  My app usually has two EC2 instances running, though sometimes it can scale to more.  I am *not* using Devise for authentication.

I noticed that the Beanstalk GUI now provides support to enable session stickiness in Elastic Load Balancer:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html#using-features.managing.elb.sessions

It seems like this would generally improve performance of most Rails apps, because there should be more cache hits if a user returns to the same machine.

My question is this: does ELB Session stickiness generally improve the performance of Rails apps, and what are the gotchas with using it, if any?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you could say that in general enabling sticky sessions improves performance - I would say you will either have occassional worse performance or it will stay about the same.

An ELB is supposed to route incoming calls to a server that has capacity to do work, when you enable sticky session the calls for a given client will keep getting routed back to the same server, even if that server is already under heavy load. You run the risk a situation that by chance a whole bunch of sessions get 'sticky' on a server, while the other server has excess capaciy.

How likely this is depends on the details of your users and application (i.e. how long a typical 'session' will be, The volume of users etc)

There are sometimes good reasons to enable session stickiness, but in my opinion, trying to improve performance is probably not one of them.

Comment: Interesting point, thanks. You could protect against that by setting reasonable auto-scaling limits, as ELB won't route to unhealthy instances.